# SESSION destroys after POST

Tags: php

I'm developing a site for someone where users can post problems to a website and the Admin of the company can view the problems and give a solution for it. I use one page that takes care of the login handling and a mysql db. The problem is that i can log in, it shows me another panel(userpanel), but whatever other button i click, it takes me back to the login panel.
It used to work as i was able to post data to my database. but suddenly after some changes on my website, it stopped working (and i can't find the problem anymore.)

When i log in, $_SESSION["LoggedIn"] gets a value and goes to the other panel on the same page with http post. when i click a button there, it seems that $_SESSION["LoggedIn"] is removed again because i check with isset if the user is logged in, otherwise it shows the userpanel.

```
//check user logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) {

//Problem posted
if (isset($_POST["plaatsen"])) {
    //Processing - plaatsen
    postProblem();
    }
} else {
//do login thing
```

}

I've attached my code here and i hope anyone can help me out.

Index.php: http://pastebin.com/BZSirUTT

Functions.php: http://pastebin.com/7Hknhm9r

Website: http://php.olvgroeninge.be/~sac.26A-07/php/Oefeningen/Oefening3/index.php (it's in dutch)

Comment: Copy the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Are all calls parsed by index.php?

Comment: nickb: I don't know where my error might be. Gurrewe: yes they are all called from functions.php

Comment: The sessions are least of your problems. You have SQL injection in your code, and passwords stored in plain-text format.

Comment: That doesn't matter yet, i'll add encryption later.

Comment: What changes did you make to the website?

Comment: I'm here to ask questions about my problem and people helping me. I'm a beginner in php so help me atleast

Comment: @Jack, i think everything worked fine until i added my divs (for the layout). I added a link to my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions typically don't disappear by themselves. If they do, assuming you did run `session_start()` first, it can be due to:

1. The session could not be saved on the server; this can be due to disc space or permission issues. It could also be due to **any page output** before the `session_start()` statement. Fortunately, you can see this by heightening the error reporting at the start of your script:

   `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(-1);`
2. The session could not be found; for session to perpetuate it requires the session id at every request. Depending on your settings, this can come from the URL (`PHPSESSID=xxx`) or cookies. In the latter case, you can verify that your browser sends the cookie by whipping up the browser developer tools.
3. You destroyed the session yourself; calling `session_unset` or `session_destroy` will clear and remove the session respectively. Make sure this doesn't happen accidentally.
4. The session is garbage collected; this normally only happens after some time of inactivity, configured using the relevant ini settings
5. The session could not be read; just like #1 but for reading.

Hope at least one of these points helps you.

---

### Debugging the session

You can add the following code to all pages to isolate the problem:

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($_COOKIE, true)), '</pre>';
session_start();
echo '<pre>Session = ', session_id(), '</pre>';
```

**Update**
The problem is that the `index.php` doesn't set any cookies; OP created a separate small test page which does set cookies. Turns out the problem is #2 then :)

Comment: In addition to what Jack has mentioned, I would also suggest taking a look at this snippet in your code:

    if (isset($_POST["uitloggen"]))
    {
        
        //Delete session
        session_unset();
        session_destroy(); 

debug/log/print out the data and check the logic i would suggest

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack. However it's still not solved. i'm having a headache of searching on this, but i just can't find it.

Comment: @Haroon that, is never called, only when the button 'uitloggen' is called and if LoggedIn is set, but it's not because the sessions seems to be destroyed after posting from another panel

Comment: @XverhelstX - How do you know it is never called ? Have you logged or confirmed this is definitely not being called?

Comment: @XverhelstX hey, i've updated the answer with a few more steps; hope you can find something in there.

Comment: Thanks Jack. The problem is, when I login, i can see that the session variabeles exits and takes me to another panel. If i press there on a button, it takes me back to the login page which it shouldn't

Comment: @XverhelstX I'm aware of the problem you're facing, but reiterating over it won't get you anywhere; did you do any browser network debugging?

Comment: I'm new into web development, so i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @XverhelstX okay, updated the answer with an easier debug way

Comment: @Jack ok, i added it to the page here: http://php.olvgroeninge.be/~sac.26A-07/php/Hoofdstuk3/index.php  don't know what to do with it otherwise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12357/discussion-between-jack-and-xverhelstx)